# Copy database to the local machine - ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-administration

I need to copy the entire database (Shema, object, data) from the server to my local machine for testing purposes. I know that there should be development database on the server, but I need to have another copy on my machine. The database is 11g and I am using SQL developer. I only found this [tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/sqldev/r31/DatabaseCopy/DatabaseCopy.html). However, I think it creates another copy on the server and does not transfer it to the local machine. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: I think you can use Oracle Data Pump

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have installed ORACLE database server on your local machine first.
Then you can use exp/imp or expdp/impdp utilities for copying entire database or schema/user.

For example how to use data pump (expdb) see this section in [Oracle documentation](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g.php#SchemaExpImp).

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `exp`/`imp` utility

```
exp userid=user/pass@prod full=y file=full.dump 
imp userid=user/pass@dev full=y file=full.dump
```

datapump is running server side and is faster but then you would have to access the file system to get the dump. If you have access to the server it's the same command just `impdp``expdp` running from the host.